# Ruling for a person taking sleeping pills regarding fajr?

Tags: salat, practical-islam, fard

Assalamu Alaikum,
I'm a patient of OCD. I take antipsychotic sleep causing pills without which I can't sleep. But they cause dizziness and when though I wake up for fajr but can't hold myself due to side affects and usually I sleep again. Is there any ruling for me. Or something I can do about this?

Comment: Consult your doctor, maybe you can adjust you sleep schedule and dosage or its timings.

Answer (score 0):

Wa alaikkum wa salaam

You can try to sleep earlier than usual and try to wake up for fajr. If you are not able to wake up in time, pray fajr whenever you wake up as soon as possible.

> 'The Prophet was asked about a man who forgets prayer or sleeps and
> misses it. He said: 'he performs it when he remembers it.'"
> https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah:695

> Abu Qatadah narrated: "They asked the Prophet about when they sIept
> past the Salat. He said: 'There is no negligence in sleep, negligence
> is only while one is awake. So when one of you forgets a Salat, or
> sleeps through it, then let him pray it when he remembers it.'"
> https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:177